# What would the opposite of "suburb" be?

Tags: antonyms

In North American English, a suburban area, or suburb, is a town or community located near a city which is mainly comprised of the homes of people who work in the city. My question is: what would the city's relationship to the suburb be called? Is there even a word for that?

Comment: The question in the title and the one in the body text are different.

Comment: @KillingTime not really, it does sort of make sense depending on what one means by "opposite"

Comment: "Urban" doesn't work?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis), a **metropolis** is a large city or conurbation which is a significant economic, political, and cultural center for a country or region, and an **important hub for regional** or international **connections, commerce, and communications**.  (bolding mine). Hub: people move in and out along arterial roads. A 'market town' was probably the mediaeval equivalent in England. But 'opposite' is so ill-defined here that I need to CV.

Comment: The city is, in relation to its suburbs, the “central city.” People “go into the city,” e.g., for opera, shopping, lunch, and the like.